# Android: How to use illumination intent API from Sony

Tags: android, api, android-intent, sony

I'm doing a simple drum set app on Android and I want to use the illumination intent api from Sony. I want to light up the illumination bar for 0.5 second when I click a button. However, when I copy and paste the code from the official website of the API into the onClickListener of the button, the bar still doesn't light up when I click the button. I already put the illumination service permission in the manifest. I'm testing the app with the Sony Xperia S LT26
This is the link to the API:  http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/experimental-apis/illumination-bar-api/  
This is the link to download the intent file: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/java-intent-file-for-the-illumintaion-bar-api/  
This is my code for the button:

```
//kick drum
    mKick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kick);
    mKick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        soundPool.play(kick, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);

        mCanvasView.soundCircle();
            Intent intent = new      Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_START_LED);
intent.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
intent.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.example.virtualdrumset");
startService(intent);


    }
});
```

Would you guys mind looking at my code and figure out how to use the intent to make the bar light up? I apologize for any mistakes or inconveniences.